# Can not install Oracle database client 18c on win 10 32 bit

Tags: oracle

The message error is 'not compatible '

I install on win 7 32 bit and win 10 32 bit

[image: i download here]

[My operatiing system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNRQQ.jpg)

[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnmAT.jpg)

Comment: Which edition of Windows are you using? Home, Education, Pro or Enterprise? (That's 10, I think Windows 7 had something similar, maybe with an Ultimate in there?) You should be okay as long as you're not using Home edition.

Comment: i use Win 10 Pro 32 bit. Please look at the pictutre below the question. I have installed win 7 sp1 32 bit. I also get that error

Comment: Posting screenshots instead of typing out information makes it harder to understand your question. Not everybody can - or is prepared to - access image dump sites.

Comment: i have posted the error ( my error)

Comment: You really haven't understood my point about screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was even not aware that Windows 10 exist also on 32-bit. The error message is quite clear.

Look at the [Hardware Component Requirements for Windows x64, 18](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntcli/hardware-component-requirements-for-Winx64.html#GUID-43CF1FEC-7C62-4BC9-96A5-C98E70FB0B5B):

> Oracle provides 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Oracle Database Client
>   for Windows. Oracle certifies 32-bit Oracle Database Client running on
>   Windows x64 only.

If you insist to have a 32-bit Windows then you can install Oracle Client 12.1, this version seems to be the last one which can be installed on 32-bit Windows, see [Oracle Database Client Hardware Requirements 12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTCLI/pre_install.htm#NTCLI1245)

> Oracle provides 32-bit (Windows x86) and 64-bit (Windows x64) versions
>   of Oracle Database Client. The 32-bit database client version runs on
>   the 32-bit version of Windows on either x86 or x64 hardware. Oracle
>   certifies 32-bit Oracle Database Client on Windows x64. Table 2-5
>   lists the operating systems supported on Windows 32-bit.
>
> Oracle Database Client for Windows is supported on the following
>   operating systems:
>
> - Windows Server 2008 - Standard, Enterprise, Datacenter, and Web editions. The Server Core option is not supported.
> - Windows 7 - Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions
> - Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 - Pro and Enterprise editions

However, it does not list Windows 10 (because it did not exist when Oracle 12.1 was released) but I assume it will work anyway.

Comment: I dont know what Oracle certifies 32 bit mean ? What i need now is Oracle database client 18c on 32 bit. Because i use Delphi 10.3.

Comment: I have posted the picture of my OS

Comment: You cannot install Oracle 18c Client on 32-bit Windows - period. What is so difficult to understand that? Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I would be very surprised if Delphi would not run on Windows 64-bit.

Comment: Delphi can run on win 64 bit. But some component can not work well on Win 64 bit. I have two computers. One for client , one for server. So Can i connect from Oracle 12c on client to 18c on server ? Defferent Oracle version ?

Comment: 32-bit applications run also on 64-bit Windows, I don't understand why you have a 32-bit Windows. Unless you have some **very** special or very old hardware there is no reason for this. Apart from that: Yes, a Oracle 12.1 client can connect to an 18c database. 32-bit or 64-bit does not matter.

Comment: i am an old man. no special. i use Oracle 12 client connect to Oracle 12 server.It work well. Thanks sir